# django Cannot combine queries once a slice has been taken

Tags: django, concatenation, slice, django-queryset

is there any way to concatenate sliced querysets?
its simplified example (i realize this particular example can be written in one query):

```
>>> ...
>>> query_set_1 = Model.objects.filter(...)[:3]
>>> query_set_2 = Model.objects.filter(...)[5:]

>>> query_set_1 | query_set_2
```

not going to work,

```
>>> AssertionError: Cannot combine queries once a slice has been taken.
```

any suggestions?
thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. But [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) will allow you to iterate through both querysets in order.

```
qiter = itertools.chain(query_set_1, query_set_2)
```

Comment: can we use the same for performing and operator to i.e., query_set_1 & query_set_2 or is there anything different?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [union()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#union) to combine two sliced queryset. Like this:

```
query_set_1 = Model.objects.filter(...)[:3]
query_set_2 = Model.objects.filter(...)[5:]

queryset = query_set_1.union(query_set_2)
```

Comment: LIMIT/OFFSET not allowed in subqueries of compound statements

Comment: sorry, I did not get what you meant. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think you should try out the answer. If you face any errors during it, please share :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
merged_queryset = [x for x in queryset1] + [y for y in queryset2]
```