# Django Rest : AssertionError: Cannot combine a unique query with a non-unique query

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, operators, django-queryset

I'm trying to get a queryset with unique instances of a model project. when I try to combine multiple querysets with & operator like:

```
projects = (q1_projects & q2_projects & q3_projects)
```

I get this error:

> AssertionError: Cannot combine a unique query with a non-unique query.

Comment: would you specify the exact query?

Comment: try this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As quoted by ruddra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54473335/11282077)

You can use [union()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#union) to combine different querysets like this:

```
q1_projects = Model.objects.filter(...)
q2_projects = Model.objects.filter(...)
q3_projects = Model.objects.filter(...)

projects = q1_projects.union(q2_projects, q3_projects)
```

That will give same result as:

```
projects = q1_projects & q2_projects & q3_projects
```

Note: The `UNION` operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use the `all=True` argument.

But if you want to `order_by` on the ForeignKey, you have to use [select()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> AssertionError: Cannot combine a unique query with a non-unique query.

When combining the query with [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) and the query without `distinct()` with ["|"(bitwise or)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators#The_Operators:) as shown below:

```py
qs1 = Food.objects.distinct().filter(name='Apple') # With "distinct()"
qs2 = Food.objects.filter(name='Orange') # Without "distinct()"
result = qs1 | qs2 # Here
```

So, I used [union()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#union) instead of "|"(bitwise or) as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
qs1 = Food.objects.distinct().filter(name='Apple')
qs2 = Food.objects.filter(name='Orange')
result = qs1.union(qs2) # Here
```